# Как исправить ошибку? Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Нашёл код в интернете для распознавания лиц, но там 3 файла python, хочу сделать 1(с интерфейсом), чтобы потом в .exe сделать, т.к. вроде бы нельзя сделать .exe из множества файлов. Делаю через tkinter. Как исправить ошибку(ниже)? И можно ли как-то перенести path, recognizer и detector внутрь функции или нельзя из-за `faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)`?

```
path = 'dataset'
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

def getImagesAndLabels(path):
    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            ids.append(id)

    return faceSamples,ids

    print ("\n [INFO] Загрузка лиц. Пожалуйта, ожидайте.")
    faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
    recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

    recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi

    print("\n [INFO] {0} лиц(а) добавлены.".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку для этой функции будет ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: getImagesAndLabels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

Comment: Ну уберите просто `path` из аргументов функции, сделайте функцию без аргументов. Вдруг так всё будет ок. `path` у вас глобальная переменная, функция возможно и так её увидит.

Comment: Ну и да, можно наверное всё это внутрь функции занести, если вы не планируете менять как-то эти переменные, если они у вас жестко будут зашиты в код.